# What is wrong with Grails 3 promises?

Tags: grails, groovy, promise

I'm trying to figure out how do Grails 3 promises work.
Here is basic example from the native docs:

```
    def test() {
      def map = new PromiseMap()
        map['one'] = { 2 * 2 }
        map['two'] = { 4 * 4 }
        map['three'] = { 8 * 8 }
        map.onComplete { Map results ->
          render results as JSON
        }
    }
```

The result is unpredictable every time.

```
{"one":4,"two":16,"three":64}
```

Next run -

```
{"one":16,"two":64,"three":4}
```

What the hell is going on? Thanks!

Comment: What version of Grails?  If that's what you're seeing, that looks like a bug

Comment: Grails Version: 3.2.6
 Groovy Version: 2.4.7
 JVM Version: 1.7.0_80

Comment: I can't replicate this with Grails 3.2.7 :-/

Comment: I tried with Grails 3.2.6 and can't replicate this either.